Number of valid mappings where $\exists \ k \in \{1,2, \cdots, n\}: $ $(1 \leq i < j \leq k) \lor (k \leq j < i \leq n) \implies f(i) < f(j)$
Suppose $S = \{1,2, \cdots, n\}$. Consider a bijective function $f : S \to S$. A valid mapping is one for which a $k \in S$ exists such that:
$$(1 \leq i < j \leq k) \lor (k \leq j < i \leq n) \implies f(i) < f(j)$$
How many such valid mappings are possible?
The way I did this is by calculating it for each $k$ - which turns out to be $C(n-1,k-1)$. Sum them up and the answer is $2^{n-1}$. Because it is $2^{n-1}$, I have a feeling that there must be some trick to do this without calculation. In other words, I'm looking for one-liner answers that use induction or some sort of a bijection trick rather than calculating it out fully.

I think this can easily be seen by induction over $n$

I suppose you want a one-liner for the $C(n-1,k-1)$ result, not for the fact that $C(n-1,0)+\cdots +C(n-1,n-1)=2^{n-1}$?

@HagenvonEitzen I am looking for a one-linear solution to the entire problem, not that part specifically.

Yes, there is an intuitive way to arrive at this result. In the following, I use $S_n = \{1, \dots, n\}$.
Then, what we are looking for is the existence of an index $k \in S_n$ such that everything to the left of index $k$ in the permutation is increasing, and everything to the right of index $k$ in the permutation is decreasing. Clearly, the element $f (k) = n$, as it is larger than any other element by your conditions. Our choice now is what lies on either side of index $k$. For this, we can consider picking a subset of any size from the set $S_{n - 1}$ to be the increasing sequence left of index $k$ in the permutation. This is obviously done in $2^{n - 1}$ ways ($2$ choices for each element, $n - 1$ elements). Each of these will be unique, because for any subset size $m$, the element $f (k) = n$ will be in the position at index $m + 1$ (so different-sized subsets must be distinct), and for a fixed $m$, the identity of the increasing sequence to the left of $f (k) = n$ is distinct.

There are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to pick a subset $T$ of $k-1$ elements from $S\setminus \{n\}$. You can identify any such $T$ with the map $f$ that first enumerates $T$ in ascending order and then (necessarily starting with $n$) $S\setminus T$ in descending order.
